# How to exclude entries with custom taxonomy from the main query

Tags: wordpress

I need to exclude custom post type entries with a specific custom taxonomy from the main query. I have reviewed other similar entries on SE but can't make it work.

This is what I have:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pojazdy', //my cpt name
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'oferta_aktywna', //my custom taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'sprzedane', //specific custom category
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: so what is the output of the above query ? you also get posts which are published under `sprzedane`?

Comment: It does not have any effect. "Sprzedane" category gets displayed too in the main query...